# View in areas cannot be located - Visual Studio 2015, C#, ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, areas

I've found many topic and suggestions on this and I think I've tried all of the combinations.

I had a working application that is going to grow larger so I decided to make use of areas. I sloughed through that and can access the controllers but then the application fails when it tries to return data to a view. I created a test data context, classes, etc. then to be sure that it wasn't something that I did wrong when moving into areas.

It's probably best to work through the somewhat smaller test situation and then apply what works to the larger actual application.

My link from `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<li><a href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", "testclasses")</a></li>
```

My model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Tracking.Areas.test.Models
{
    public class testclass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My testAreaRegistration:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Tracking.Areas.test
{
    public class testAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "test";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "test_default",
                //"test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                "test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My test controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tracking.Areas.test.Models;
using Tracking.DAL.Test;

namespace Tracking.Areas.test.Controllers
{
    [RouteArea("test")]
    public class testclassesController : Controller
    {
        private testcontext db = new testcontext();

        // GET: test/testclasses
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.spas.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: test/testclasses/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            testclass testclass = await db.spas.FindAsync(id);
            if (testclass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(testclass);
        }

        // GET: test/testclasses/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: test/testclasses/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "ID")] testclass testclass)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.spas.Add(testclass);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(testclass);
        }

        // GET: test/testclasses/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            testclass testclass = await db.spas.FindAsync(id);
            if (testclass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(testclass);
        }

        // POST: test/testclasses/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "ID")] testclass testclass)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(testclass).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(testclass);
        }

        // GET: test/testclasses/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            testclass testclass = await db.spas.FindAsync(id);

            if (testclass == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(testclass);
        }

        // POST: test/testclasses/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            testclass testclass = await db.spas.FindAsync(id);
            db.spas.Remove(testclass);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

My RouteConfig file

```
namespace Tracking
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

My Global.asax.cs file

```
namespace Tracking
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried with and without `[RouteArea("test")]` in the controller; I've tried multiple options with adding a controller to the area registration file, removing the area name from in front of controller in the area registration file, and many other combinations.

The code finds the controller and model as I put breakpoints in those and reach them - when it attempts to return the view I get the error message about the index view not being found in the standard locations - it doesn't search within the areas at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have an inconsistence in your "convention over configuration" setup. Might be helpful to add the error message and your solution structure. You should check, for example, that the Index.cshtml is found in the Areas\test\Views\testclasses folder. The only thing that I see at a first glance is that you didn't modify your action link to include the area. You should try:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test", "Index", "testclasses", new { Area = "test" }, new{})
```

P.S.> I would recommend using camel case notation for the class names and areas... you know, for the clean code sake. Not to mention that you never know when you might stumble upon a case sensitive convention....

Comment: Thank you!!  I had tried the area in my ActionLink but without the additional new{} statement.   This now works...but it did break my shared layout links (it seems as though once I transition to the new area using the ActionLink it tries to find the non-area links (for example the default contact and home links) in the area instead of out in the native folders.  I will work on this.  Regarding camel case - for actual classes I do this...this was just a quick and dirty test to get a clean test of a new class rather than those that I had moved over into a new area. 
 Again - thank you!

Comment: Fixing the _Layout.cshtml file was easy - I just had to add a blank area in the same style as above.  <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { })</li> Thank you!